# addClass('active') with window.location.pathname - url is without file extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, navigation

this is my first question here, I'm stuck and didn't found the answer I was looking for. I have this situation where I want to `.addClass('active')` to navigation link. It works well if my `window.location.pathname` has extension like `.html` or `.php`.

I have "nice" URL via .htaccess which hides extension of files and look something like this:

http://mydomain/biography  instead of http://mydomain/biography.php

So here is the code that I wrote
HTML

```
    <nav>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="biography.php">Bio</a></li>
         <li><a href="somelink.php">Something</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
       <ul>
    </nav>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("nav [href]").each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        }   
    });
 });
```

I think .htaccess code is not necessary for this kind of situation

Is there any way to parse `this.href` and to exclude file extension (in my case .php) or is there better way to deal with this?

Thanks in advance! =D

Comment: It would be better (and more reliable) to do this server-side in your PHP

Comment: you can always regex format the strings before you compare

Answer (score 0):

Phillip100 - thanks man, you helped me with this one, maybe not directly, but your code forced me to look it from other angle, I did not replaced, i just added extension! =D

the code that worked for me was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var location = window.location.href + '.php';        
   $("nav [href]").each(function() {
    if (this.href == location) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

I tried to make it work via pathname, but href also helps, with this code I got what I wanted, thanks to all of you who helped! =D

Answer (score 0):

//100% WORK

```
$("nav [href]").each(function() {
      var pathname = window.location.pathname;
      var plink = this.href.search(pathname);
      if(plink > 0){
         $(this).addClass("current");
      }
    });
```

Comment: This creates a new regular expression from the pathname, which may have side effects. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) for more information. You would want .includes or .indexOf